# how can get simple function

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, calculator

how can get $y$ simple function of $x$ from :

$$
\frac{2 \sqrt{y} \sqrt{y-b} \log \left(\sqrt{y-b}+\sqrt{y}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{A y (y-b)}{b}}}+\text{constant} =x$$

where :

$$ y=y_0 at x=0$$

and can i plot $y$ against $x$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Start simplifying, as much as you can, the lhs
$$
\frac{2 \sqrt{y} \sqrt{y-b} \log \left(\sqrt{y-b}+\sqrt{y}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{A y (y-b)}{b}}}$$

The denominator is almost present in the numerator then you can almost remove it. Continue sending to the rhs everything wchich does not involve $y$.

I am sure that you can take from here.